# How can I rectify Invalid Identifier Error in Oracle Apex?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have this PL/SQL Code:

```
Declare
p_password Varchar2(20);
Begin
  select PASSWORD into p_password from CSD_USERS
    where ID = :APP_USER
    and Password = :P13_OLD_PASSWORD;

    RETURN TRUE;
    
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RETURN FALSE;
end;
```

And i'm getting the "Invalid Identifier" error at the WHERE clause for ID (ORA-00904: "ID": Invalid Identifier".
Now, in the table CSD_USERS the ID Column the name is USERS_ID. Do I need to replace ID with USERS_ID or is there a way to handle the error with ID?

Comment: "Now, in the table `CSD_USERS` the ID Column the name is `USERS_ID`. Do I need to replace ID with `USERS_ID`" Yes, if you named the column something else then use the correct name.